# Hibernate Many-to-Many relationship with an additional table

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jta

I'm working with Hibernate and I'd like to be able to create a many-to-many-to-many relationship. The current scenario being: -

A band may play at many venues and a venue may have many bands.

```
BAND >------< VENUE
```

This would constitute as a many to many relationship, so I use a join table, such as: -

```
BAND ----< BAND_VENUES >---- VENUE
```

I am capable of creating this using both hibernate or SQL; see the test case: -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Band")
public class Band implements Serializable,
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "bandId" )
    @GenericGenerator(name = "bandId", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String bandId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "Band_Venues",
    joinColumns =  
    {
        @JoinColumn(name = "bandId")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = 
    {
        @JoinColumn(name = "venueId")
    })
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Venue")
public class Venue implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "venueId" )
    @GenericGenerator(name = "venueId", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String venueId;
}
```

This seems very simple and makes sense to me.

Where I get confused is if I add another many to many relationship using the following scenario.

A band may play at many venues at different date/times, so: -

```
BAND ----< GIG_DATES >-----< GIG_DATES_VENUES >---- VENUE
```

Is what I believe the relationship should be however using hibernate, I don't actually have a mapping for 'BAND_VENUES' so how do I go about creating the relationship?

I am using annotations and not a mapping file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you like to hear but I'd approach this slightly differently.

Doesn't a band play at a venue *at a particular date/time*?

Hence, I'd conceptually "extend" the initial `BAND_VENUES` join table from

> BAND ----< BAND_VENUES >---- VENUE

and add a time stamp to it.

This naturally leads to a new entity `GIG` which replaces the (anonymous) `BAND_VENUES` join table. It has a

- many-to-one relationship to `BAND`
- many-to-one relationship to `VENUE`
- timestamp
- ...

Comment: I see, so does the date/time then become part of the composite key? Otherwise I assume that a band could only ever play at a venue once

Comment: The answer provided has solved my problem so I'm marking this as the correct answer as it was answered first

Comment: You'd better treat the new Gig entity as all the other entities: assign it an auto-generated, single-column ID. Add a unique constraint on the three other fields if you want, but single-column, autogenerated keys are cleaner, more efficient, ans easier to use. And that allows changing the date of a gig, which wouldn't be possible if the date was part of the PK.

Comment: yes, that's certainly better...I should have included this in my comment, sry

Answer (score 2):

On the moment when many-to-many relationship gets attributes, it is not relationship anymore. Relationships do not have attributes in JPA, entities do.

Such a "relationship with attributes" is modeled as an intermediate entity which will have many-to-one relationship to original entities, in this case to `Band` and to `Venue`. It goes roughly as follows:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(GigId.class)
public class Gig {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Band band
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Venue venue;

}

public class GigId implements Serializable{
    private String band;

    private String venue;
    ...
    //date
}

public class Band { ..
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "band")
    private Collection<Gig> gigs;
    ...
}

public class Venue {..
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "venue")
   private Collection<Gig> gigs;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I see, so does the date/time then become part of the composite key? Otherwise I assume that a band could only ever play at a venue once

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I've given it +1 however the answer by Marcel Stör is the same and helped just as much and since he posted first I'm marking his as the correct answer :-(

Comment: +1 for this part: `On the moment when many-to-many relationship gets attributes, it is not relationship anymore. Relationships do not have attributes in JPA, entities do.` This is a key part that they accepted answer does not have.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Marcel (he beat me to it but I already had this written).  By making a 'join' table called Performance, you basically have the same thing. (Excuse my pseudo code) Roughly something like:

```
@Entity
class Band 
{
   @OneToMany
   Performance performance;
}

@Entity   
class Performance
{  
   @ManyToOne
   Band band;
   @OneToOne (or many to many is sometimes easier to work with)
   Venue Venue;
   Date date;
}

@Entity
class Venue {
   String address;
}
```